# Not getting along with the form API tutorial

Tags: forms

I am using Drupal 7, and I want to build a form. I tried to follow the tutorial in "Pro Drupal 7 Development"; I created a .module and .info file, which are supposed to work, I activated the module, and now I don't find the form.

How can I see the form in the front end, or at least at the back end? Is there a URL Drupal is giving to this module? How can I see it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [hook_menu()](http://api.drupal.org/api/function/hook_menu/6).

```
function YourModuleName_menu() {

 $items['testform'] = array(
   'title' => 'Test form',
   'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
   'page arguments' => array('your_form_function'),
   'access arguments' => array('access content'),
   'type' => MENU_CALLBACK
 );

 return $items;
}
```

Access the page from example.com/testform, where example.com is your site address.

You can also create a block from your form to access it.